# How to click link X in Page A to visit Page B and click link Y? (just through link X in Page A)

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I have a strange requirement. I have a php page called PAGE-A. There is an anchor link in it, called LINK X. There is another php page called PAGE-B and there is another anchor link in it called LINK Y. What I want is to click on LINK X and it gets me to open PAGE-B and then clicks on link Y by itself.

Comment: use javascipt for this propouse, at the click on Link Y

Comment: Is `LINK X` the only way to get to `PAGE B`?

Comment: Yes, link X is on Page A and the only way to get to Page B is to click on Link X on Page A

Comment: I think that most browser won't let you do any action on page load with Javascript, you need an action from the user to trigger any js code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some jQuery (could also be done with plain JS too) like, place that code in Page Y and when it loads it will click your anchor link. Change the id in the javascript to match your's.

```js
(function (window, document, $, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myLink').trigger("click");
    });

})(window, document, jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.google.com" id="myLink">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do that through a GET parameter. I don't know if there are better solutions, but it will at least work :D

add to the href of link X '?y=true'. Then, in page B, add some javascript like this:

```
var y = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.match(/(\?|&)y\=([^&]*)/)[2]);
if(y != "" && y == true){ 
  document.getElementById("linkYId").click();
}
```

Hope it works!